# How can I test Memory leaks of my application in mobile device especially in iOS and Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, memory-management

I am a manual tester and don't any of the tool so I need to know how can we check memory leaks in mobile device itself. Or is there any other method to test it? without having the knowledge of coding.

Comment: Have you tried googlig for the answer?

Comment: Yes! but all were regarding coding. I didn't find any suitable point in accordance to testing

Answer (score 10):

### iOS

For iOS use Instruments. See [Locating Memory Issues in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html). Use the Leaks instrument of the Instruments analysis tool to find objects in your app that are no longer referenced and reachable.

[image]

### Android

For Android use [Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php) or Android Debug Monitor as described in [Investigating Your RAM Usage](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html)

While using the tools described above, you should aggressively stress your app code and try forcing memory leaks. One way to provoke memory leaks in your app is to let it run for a while before inspecting the heap. Leaks will trickle up to the top of the allocations in the heap. However, the smaller the leak, the longer you need to run the app in order to see it.

[image]